# Storing a string of inputs into a struct in C

Tags: c, string, struct, user-input, scanf

was wondering how I would be able to store a user inputted string in the format "string,character,integer,integer"
into a struct.
For example storing "apple,c,5,10" into

```
typedef struct {
char item[80];
char letter;
int x,y;
}information;

information apple;
```

I am trying to avoid going through using scanf and a long piece of code to make the comma into a delimiter so wondering if there was any other way to quickly read from scanf and chucking this information into the struct

Comment: C is a low level language and is generally not type safe like Python and many others.  You have to do it the hard way or your life will be miserable because of the opportunities for errors like data validation, buffer overruns, etc.  :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify complex formats using `scanf`, like:

```
scanf("%79[^,],%c,%d,%d", apple.item, &apple.letter, &apple.x, &apple.y);
```

`%79[^,]` means scan anything that is not a comma character, up to 79 characters.

Note that this does no error handling if the user enters a poorly formatted string, like `"aaa;b;1;2"`. For that, you'll need to write a lot more code. See `strtok`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple format specifiers in the format string to `scanf()` to scan all the input *at once*, through a *comma-seperated* user input, like

```
int ret = -1;
if ((ret = scanf("%79[^,],%c,%d,%d", apple.item, &apple.letter, &apple.x, &apple.y)) != 4)
                       //always check the return value of scanf()                       
{
   printf("scanf() failed\n");
   //do something to avoid usage of the member variables of "apple"
}
```

However, I'll recommend the *long way*, like

- read the line using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
- tokenize using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) and `,` as delimiter
- use the token (or convert using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), as required).

Much safe and robust.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read using the func `read()` then just split the string using `strtok()`

Here's some references :

strtok : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

read  : http://linux.die.net/man/2/read